# OpenCVの実行ができない

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, opencv

失礼しました。
ubuntu 14.10で、

```
apt-get install libopencv-dev
```

を実行したところ、インストールは無事止まることなく終わったようなのですが
spyderで下記のコードを実行すると

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import cv2

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # 画像取得
    im_in = cv2.imread("test.jpg")
    # 画像表示
    cv2.imshow("Show Image",im_in)
    # キー入力待機
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    # ウィンドウ破棄
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    # 画像保存
    cv2.imwrite('test2.jpg',im_in)
```

下記のエラーが出ます

```
error: /home/memeda/ドキュメント/bal/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/
window.cpp:293: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the
library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu
or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or
configure script in function cvShowImage
```

また、エラーをgoogleで検索したところ、

http://blogs.yahoo.co.jp/airmikan/33712965.html

下記のパッケージをインストールするそうですが、

```
gtk2-devel.x86_64
```

aptでは見つからないと、yumのepelでは利用できませんと表示されました。

利用できるレポジトリ、代替できるパッケージ等がありましたら教えてください。

Comment: 少なくとも bash の構文エラーについては `<epel>` の部分が問題です．ただ ubuntu をお使いということなのでたぶん yum じゃなくて apt を使うのが良くて，パッケージのインストールなら `sudo apt install (パッケージ名)` .

Comment: レポジトリの追加は出来ました。ありがとうございます。
訂正して再度質問します。

Comment: （状況は把握しきってないですが，）エラーメッセージには " If you are on Ubuntuor Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config," とあるようですけれど，それは試されましたか？

Comment: はい。両方最新バージョンでした。

Comment: http://www.icrus.org/horiba/article/2014_11_07_01.php